# Answer shows up as deleted in flag list, but isn't

Tags: support, flags, deleted-answers

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908262/php-class-to-generate-sitemap/5908296#5908296) as "low quality".

In my flag overview, the post shows up as deleted:

[image]

However, it clearly isn't. Also, my manual delete vote doesn't seem to register.

Is this a bug, or was the answer undeleted later?

Comment: Hmm, according to the comment you left, you've tried casting a delete vote. I just did the same thing, `delete(2)` appeared, and then upon refresh, I just see `delete`. Not sure why this post is refusing to be deleted... Do you see a vote counter?

Comment: @Cody nope, I don't see a counter at all. Strange.

Comment: I flagged your answer without reading it, and maliciously gained flag weight, heheh, :P

Comment: @YOU we could start a flag weight ring! We would become the heaviest guys around within a few days. Oh boy!

Comment: LoL, and will get abuse badges next day. heheh :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to revisions list, OP deleted and undeleted back, I am not sure this reset the flag or not though.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5908296/revisions

[image]

Comment: Ah-ha! So it was community deleted, and the OP undeleted. Thanks, didn't think of looking in the revision history.

Comment: @Pekka, btw, your flag is registered as valid or invalid or still under review?  I am just curious!

Comment: it seems to have been marked as valid. I was able to flag again but that flag isn't showing up in my history.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer was undeleted later.**

The [revisions page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5908296/revisions) for the post confirms that it was deleted by Gordon and Roshan. And then it was later undeleted by Roshan.

Apparently this doesn't reset the flag page.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in which your flag history can tell you that a post has been deleted.

- “♦ Post Deleted” means that at some point after your flag, the action of deleting the post happened. (“deleted” is used in an active mode.)
- The post title appearing in a gray background means that the post is currently in the deleted state. (“deleted” is used as an ajective.)

If you see “Post Deleted” on a non-deleted post, it means the post was deleted then restored (which could happen legitimately if the author replaced the previously bad content by a worthwhile answer).